# Can I backup data without Booting?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-7-backup

I am using Windows 7. Recently, when I turned on my PC, it ran CHKDSK on one of my drive and after that, when the computer booted, I was unable to access that drive without formatting it. Now whenever I turn on my PC, CHKDSK runs and I cancel it since I don't want to format my other drives because there are some extremely important files in them. But now when I turn on my PC, it doesn't boot up. It's stuck at the Windows Logo and when I try to run it from safe mode, it gets stuck while loading CLASSPNP.SYS. I have tried all the solutions from microsoft community and youtube and the appropriate answer seems to reinstall Windows. Since Microsoft is providing Windows 10 iso for free on it's site (can anyone please confirm it), I was wondering that if I install it, will my files be preserved? If not, is there any way to backup my files without booting my pc or without the OS?

Comment: Windows 10 isn’t free.  While you can download the ISO, it doesn’t do you much good, without a license.  A Windows 10 ISO cannot repair a Windows 7 installation.  A Windows 10 ISO cannot be used to upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 unless you can boot into Windows (which by your own admission isn’t currently possible).  It sounds like you have storage devices that have failed hence the reason your being prompted to format unallocated partitions.  Restoring from a backup is your only solution at this point.  If that isn’t possible consider the data gone.

Comment: So what if I install windows 10 via iso in the boot menu? Will this preserve my data (except c drive)?

Comment: `chkdisk` does not format disks.

Comment: I know. But after chkdsk completed and my computer booted, I tried to open that drive but an error popped up which said I needed to format it before using it.

Comment: @AshutoshBudhdeo - Installing Windows from the boot menu will NOT preserve your data.  Which is what my original comment indicates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can back up data from a hard disk without booting the operating system that's on it.

Option A: boot your computer from another hard disk, DVD, or a USB drive. You can create a bootable DVD/USB yourself if you have another computer or a friend with one.

Option B: boot another computer and connect your hard disk there. This requires you to remove your hard disk and either install it in the other computer or to have a means of connecting it to the other computer ready.

Comment: @Ashutosh Budhdeo, this is correct, but be aware that you cannot use a simple backup like this to recover your files that disappeared when you formatted the drive.